# Sql server 2008 backup - backup tail of the log

Tags: sql-server

Setting up maintenance plan for sql server 2008 backup

Don't understand what exactly backup tail of the log, i read some ms articles about this. Still dumb enough for database to figure out what need to do.

For regular backup strategy do i need to select backup tail of the log option? What would i loose or get with this option?

If i select it what i need to know for restore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, backup tail is a disaster recovery option. You do them just before attempting to do a restore, after a disaster: you attempt to backup the log tail, if possible, in hope that all data can be recovered.

For regular maitenance jobs, you do a normal log backup. See [Tail-Log Backups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179314.aspx).

Comment: Thanks now i can sleep in peace

Comment: But if I'm able to make a backup after a disaster why would I even need to restore, aren't I up and running?

Comment: @crokusek: 'Disaster' is not always a black or white situation. eg. the database is in emergency mode, perhaps you lost a drive with some of the NDF files but the system can boot. DB is not available, but tail of log is, so you back it up. You can't always take the tail of the log backup, but when you do can, then you should.